# Why do arrow functions accept function invocations in body?

Tags: javascript

This is so strange! I'm looking at AWS Lambda example code, and they do a strange ES6 declaration for their callbacks:

```
const done = (err, res) => callback(null, {
    statusCode: err ? '400' : '200',
    body: err ? err.message : JSON.stringify(res),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
});
```

So, I made my own simplified example to try to make sense of this declaration.

```js
function add (x, y) {
  return x + y
}

var done = (a, b) => add(1,7)

console.log(done(1,2)) // 8
```

The code above logs 8 at the end. I thought it would be the equivalent of:

```js
function add (x, y) {
  return x + y
}

var done = function (a, b) { add(1,7) }

console.log(done(1,2)) // undefined
```

But it's not. It produced undefined. Can someone explain how the function invocation in the fat arrow declaration doesn't just execute and return a value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the right hand side of the `=>` is a statement (rather than a block) there is an implicit `return`.

Your function expression…

> ```
> var done = function (a, b) { add(1,7) }
> ```

… omits that return statement. It should be:

```
var done = function (a, b) { return add(1,7) }
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't seem to accept yet. So, in the AWS example, done becomes a function that returns a the execution of the callback function with particular parameters?

Comment: @Costa — It returns the value got by calling the function named `callback`

Answer (score 1):

`return`

Arrow functions without curly brackets can only be one line and will automatically return.

Babeljs.io has a good example of what ES2016 looks like in ES5 http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code=function%20add%20(x%2C%20y)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20x%20%2B%20y%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20done%20%3D%20(a%2C%20b)%20%3D%3E%20add(1%2C7)%0A%0Aconsole.log(done(1%2C2))%20%2F%2F%208

Comment: "can only be one line" — Lines are largely meaningless in JS (except when they interact with ASI), the example in the question has 7 lines to the right of the `=>`.